# Load all friends using google play services

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/google-play-game-services/7190/10 here there is a code that is for loading friends. This code is old and I have updated it to new version:

```
public static void loadFriends(JSONObject parameters) {
        if (mFriends.size() > 0) {
            mFriends.clear();
        }

        ((AppActivity)mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                 Games.Players.loadInvitablePlayers(((AppActivity)mContext).getApiClient(), FRIENDS_PER_PAGE, false).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LoadPlayersResult>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onResult(LoadPlayersResult result) {

                            Log.w("GOOGLE SERVICES ****** ", "onResult");
                            PlayerBuffer playerBuffer = result.getPlayers();
                            for (Player player : playerBuffer) {
                                mFriends.add(player);
                                Log.i("GOOGLE SERVICES ---- ", String.format("Found player with id [%s] and display name [%s]", player.getPlayerId(), player.getDisplayName()));
                            }

                            if (playerBuffer.getCount() == FRIENDS_PER_PAGE) {
                                Log.w("GOOGLE SERVICES +++=== ", "loadMoreInvitablePlayers");
                                Games.Players.loadMoreInvitablePlayers(((AppActivity)mContext).getApiClient(), FRIENDS_PER_PAGE);
                            } else {
                                // call out and return all the friends 
                                Log.w("GOOGLE SERVICES======== ", "call out and return all the friends");
                                for (Player friend : mFriends) {
                                    Log.i("GOOGLE SERVICES", String.format("Found player with id [%s] and display name [%s]", friend.getPlayerId(), friend.getDisplayName()));
                                }
                            }
                        } // onResult

                 }); // loadInvitablePlayers
            } // run
        }); // runOnUiThread
    }
```

But this works strangely. It loads from the first call 20 players, whereas the page size is 10 and  considers that all the players are loaded. But I actually have more friends. How to load all my friends?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html#loadInvitablePlayers(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20int,%20boolean)), that behavior is normal:

"The number of entries to request for this initial page. Note that if cached data already exists, **the returned buffer may contain more than this size**, but it is guaranteed to contain **at least** this many if the collection contains enough records. This must be a value between 1 and 25."